# Cropped Bitmap not fitting to the center. (Hand free cropping.)

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-bitmap, drawbitmap

I'm trying to crop image using draw. And Its cropping as expected but i think not scaling the cropped part to center of new bitmap. You can see 2 pictures 1. Picture is what i own now. And 2. Picture is what i expect.

**ORIGINAL IMAGE.**

[image]

**WHAT I HAVE**

[image]

**WHAT I NEED**

[image]

I'm Cropping on SomeView and sending points to CropActivity and CropActivity crops the image and send it to the MainActivity.

Here is my `CropActivity.Java`

```
public class CropActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView compositeImageView;
    boolean crop;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cropview);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            crop = extras.getBoolean("crop");
        }
        int widthOfscreen = 512;
        int heightOfScreen = 512;

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        try {
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        widthOfscreen = dm.widthPixels;
        heightOfScreen = dm.heightPixels;

        compositeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.our_imageview);

        Bitmap bitmap2 = SomeView.bitmap;

        Bitmap resultingImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthOfscreen,
                heightOfScreen, bitmap2.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        Path path = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < SomeView.points.size(); i++) {
            path.lineTo(SomeView.points.get(i).x, SomeView.points.get(i).y);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        if (crop) {
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        } else {
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
        compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(resultingImage);


        Button donb = findViewById(R.id.donb);

        donb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

                ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                resultingImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream);
                byte[] byteArray = bStream.toByteArray();

                returnIntent.putExtra("result",byteArray);
                setResult(2,returnIntent);
                finish();
             //   donb.setText("Dondum");
            }
        });






    }
}
```

Here is my `SomeView.Java`

```
public class SomeView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private Paint paint;
    public static List<Point> points;
    int DIST = 2;
    boolean flgPathDraw = true;
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    Point mfirstpoint = null;
    boolean bfirstpoint = false;

    Point mlastpoint = null;

  public static Bitmap bitmap;
    Context mContext;


    public SomeView(Context c, Bitmap b) {
        super(c);

        bitmap = b;
        mContext = c;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 20 }, 0));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);


        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();

        bfirstpoint = false;
    }

    public SomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        bfirstpoint = false;

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Path path = new Path();
        boolean first = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2) {
            Point point = points.get(i);
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
            } else if (i < points.size() - 1) {
                Point next = points.get(i + 1);
                path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, next.x, next.y);
            } else {
                mlastpoint = points.get(i);
                path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        // return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = (int) event.getX();
        point.y = (int) event.getY();

        if (flgPathDraw) {

            if (bfirstpoint) {

                if (comparepoint(mfirstpoint, point)) {
                    // points.add(point);
                    points.add(mfirstpoint);
                    flgPathDraw = false;
                    showcropdialog();
                } else {
                    points.add(point);
                }
            } else {
                points.add(point);
            }

            if (!(bfirstpoint)) {

                mfirstpoint = point;
                bfirstpoint = true;
            }
        }

        invalidate();
        Log.e("Hi  ==>", "Size: " + point.x + " " + point.y);

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            mlastpoint = point;
            if (flgPathDraw) {
                if (points.size() > 12) {
                    if (!comparepoint(mfirstpoint, mlastpoint)) {
                        flgPathDraw = false;
                        points.add(mfirstpoint);
                        showcropdialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean comparepoint(Point first, Point current) {
        int left_range_x = (int) (current.x - 3);
        int left_range_y = (int) (current.y - 3);

        int right_range_x = (int) (current.x + 3);
        int right_range_y = (int) (current.y + 3);

        if ((left_range_x < first.x && first.x < right_range_x)
                && (left_range_y < first.y && first.y < right_range_y)) {
            if (points.size() < 10) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void fillinPartofPath() {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = points.get(0).x;
        point.y = points.get(0).y;

        points.add(point);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void resetView() {
        points.clear();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        flgPathDraw = true;
        invalidate();
    }

    private void showcropdialog() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        // Yes button clicked
                        // bfirstpoint = false;

                        intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("crop", true);
                        ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        // No button clicked

                        intent = new Intent(mContext, CropActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("crop", false);
                        ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                        bfirstpoint = false;
                        // resetView();

                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage("Do you Want to save Crop or Non-crop image?")
                .setPositiveButton("Crop", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Non-crop", dialogClickListener).show()
                .setCancelable(false);
    }
}


class Point {

    public float dy;
    public float dx;
    float x, y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

And I'm really thankful about giving answers to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching a solution for a 2 days. I looked all cropping answers in StackOverflow and did'nt find any solution to make it center. And trimming extra spaces. So I found a solution for avoiding extra spaces on cropped image....

Using this function is making new Bitmap without extra spaces. Use function before `resultingImage.`

```
 static Bitmap trim(Bitmap source) {
        int firstX = 0, firstY = 0;
        int lastX = source.getWidth();
        int lastY = source.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[source.getWidth() * source.getHeight()];
        source.getPixels(pixels, 0, source.getWidth(), 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        loop:
        for (int x = 0; x < source.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y++) {
                if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    firstX = x;
                    break loop;
                }
            }
        }
        loop:
        for (int y = 0; y < source.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = firstX; x < source.getWidth(); x++) {
                if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    firstY = y;
                    break loop;
                }
            }
        }
        loop:
        for (int x = source.getWidth() - 1; x >= firstX; x--) {
            for (int y = source.getHeight() - 1; y >= firstY; y--) {
                if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    lastX = x;
                    break loop;
                }
            }
        }
        loop:
        for (int y = source.getHeight() - 1; y >= firstY; y--) {
            for (int x = source.getWidth() - 1; x >= firstX; x--) {
                if (pixels[x + (y * source.getWidth())] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    lastY = y;
                    break loop;
                }
            }
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, firstX, firstY, lastX - firstX, lastY - firstY);
    }
```